# How to create a global method in C# that can be called without prefixing the classname?

Tags: c#, .net, function, static

If I want to make a function that can be called from every location in my project, I create static class with a static function, but I still have to refer to the function as `Class.Method` instead of `Method` even if I import the static class with `using`. How can you do this?

Comment: My question is... _why?_

Comment: Ask yourself: how many times have I *consumed* such a feature in C#? The answer is zero. This should tell you something.

Comment: @DaveZych .NET creators decided to go different way than Java creators.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov This cannot be done in `Java` either.  Methods in Java must be contained within a type.

Comment: there are many obscure features of all languages. a significant perentage of SO traffic is about obscure features

Comment: @Servy In Java you can import static function from class. So you don't need to prefix the method with class name.

Comment: Use VB modules if you want this feature.

Comment: @DaveZych Im porting a Java library to C# and I want the resulting code to look as much as possible as the original, because it will make it easier to sync changes in the future.

Comment: @Muis - mirror is two way street :)... consider to change original to match features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the Build 2014 keynote it was announce that the following should work in the next version:

```
using Class;

...

Method(...);
```

Basically, exactly what you wanted. The `using Class;` imports the static methods from the `Class` type so that they don't need to be referenced from the type.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot.  Functions must be declared within a type in C#.

Comment: There are no functions in C# actually, they are methods - that's why they need to be inside a type

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to the **STATIC** method as Class.Method() unless you are inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you cannot import a static class. You only import a `namespace` in which it is contained.

You actually cannot do it - that is the basic principle of OOP - everything has it's class. Methods in `static class`es are the replacement for the global functions in C++